# Which books is Ross Douthat citing in relation to his conversion to Catholicism

Tags: catholicism

50'35" into [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCWIB0RZXyc) video (*Faith Is Not a Sideshow - Ross Douthat at the University of Michigan*), [New York Times columnist](https://www.nytimes.com/column/ross-douthat) [Ross Douthat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross_Douthat) says this about his conversion to Catholicism (as a teenager):

> [...] I made the conversion to Catholicism more in a straightforward
>   intellectual -- I read a bunch of books and found Catholic
>   claims convincing -- kind of way [...]

Can somebody tell whether he identified (some of) these books elsewhere and if so, which ones are they?

Comment: The only thing I remember from Ross Douthat was the [Ross Douthat controversy](http://www.ncregister.com/search/results?q=douthat) in which he espoused some remarks that raised the hackles of Catholic intellectuals and/or traditionalists. I'm not sure he's the #1 best guy to build a bibliography from, but YMMV.  Anyway, the "Catholic Intellectual" movement from the early 20th century which owes itself to Cardinal John Henry Newman and various other authors and philosophers, as well as the writings of the Popes of the late 19th century.

Comment: @PeterTurner These are good pointers, thanks.

Comment: FWIW I tweeted him a request to answer this question; it would be cool to get some 1st hand source answers to stop by and answer questions like they do for programming questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @PeterTurner Excellent & I agree that would be cool. I've meanwhile learned from ingesting other sources that [Chesterton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._K._Chesterton) would presumably also be on that list.